# Permanent redirect through htaccess in magento

Tags: .htaccess, magento, redirect

how can i redirect using htaccess in magento , i need to redirect an old url link to the new articles cms page
  i tried to put the redirect link on the root htaccess but doesnot do anything

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine on
 Redirect 301 https://www.website.com/articles?article=153 https://www.website.com/history-of-starbucks 
 RewriteBase /
```

Please, any help will be greatly appreciated

Thank you in advance.
jarus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this instead of the rule-set in your question:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}    !/history-of-starbucks      [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}   ^article=153/?              [NC]
RewriteRule ^articles     /history-of-starbucks?  [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: i just have one more question can i do this for other older url links also

Comment: Which strings would be dynamic and which fixed?

Comment: /articles?article will be fixed only the article number will be variable and the article key(eg. history-of-starbucks) related to the article number will be different for every article

Comment: Unfortunately the problem for making a global rule-set is the article key (history-of-starbucks) is not part of the incoming URL so it has to be hard coded it manually. But yes, you can use the same code for other links (Without repeating the first 3 lines though).

Comment: Thank you faa, appreciate  your help :)